# Why use boost disable_interruption when you want to test for interruption_requested()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-thread

A lot of places I see code like this:

```
void threadFunction()
{
    boost::this_thread::disable_interruption disable;
    while (!boost::this_thread::interruption_requested())
    {
            //do stuff
    }
}
```

For me this looks like I "disable" the thread function from being interrupted, but then again I test for an interruption.
Miraculously, it works. 
Can someone explain to me what it actually does behind the scenes?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`disable_interruption` prevents the thread from actually being interrupted; it doesn't prevent the interrupted status being set. Then `interruption_requested` tests whether the interrupted status *has* been set.

See the Boost documentation: specifically [the "Interruption" section](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption)

Various methods are classed as 'interruption points' and will throw an exception if they are called when interruption has been requested, unless interruption has been disabled.

So in short:

- Disabling interruption prevents interruption from actually stopping the thread, but the interruption still marks the thread as 'interrupt requested'
- The `interruption_requested` method checks whether an interrupt has been requested